# Minimize $P=\sqrt{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc}+\sqrt{a+b+c-1}$ when $ab+bc+ca=3.$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0:ab+bc+ca=3.$ Find the minimal value $$P=\sqrt{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc}+\sqrt{a+b+c-1}.$$
I think $2+\sqrt{2}$ is desired result. $P$ attain this value when $a=b=c=1.$

I use $a+b+c\ge \sqrt{3(ab+bc+ca)}=3$ and we need to prove $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc\ge 4.$$
But it is wrong when $c=0,b=3,a=1.$

I got stuck here. Can you help me prove the OP? Thanks.

Also, I want to know how to eliminate the radical signs.

A week and without any success. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: It is frowned upon to repost. I saw the same question yesterday, with a link to AOPS. It received comments guiding you to this attempt.

Comment: @AnneBauval can you share the link of the earlier post if possible?

Comment: @DS Unfortunately not. I didn't save it and I suspect it was deleted by its author.

Comment: We may use the pqr method. But it is not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi But how to reduce the cyclic yield $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ into $pqr$ ?

Comment: @Helloworld We can deal with it in this manner: Let $p := a + b + c, q := ab + bc + ca = 3, r := abc$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &a^2b + b^2c + c^2a \\
 ={}& \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2}{2}
 - \frac{ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2 - (a^2b + b^2c + c^2a)}{2}\\
 ={}& \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2}{2}
 - \frac{(a - b)(b - c)(c - a)}{2}\\
 \ge{}& \frac{a^2b + b^2c + c^2a + ab^2 + bc^2 + ca^2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}}{2}\\
 ={}& \frac{3p - 3r}{2} - \frac12 \sqrt{-27r^2 + (-4p^3 + 54p)r + 9p^2 - 108}. 
\end{align*}

Comment: By the way, we can find the closed form minimum of $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc$ as a function of $p$ when $a, b, c\ge 0$ with $a + b + c = p$ ($p \ge 3$ is fixed) and $ab + bc + ca = 3$. But the reasoning is complicated.

Comment: Your comment is very useful. Thank you. Now, it is just a calculating manners, right?

Comment: @Helloworld But it is not nice. Hope to see nice solution. By the way, you may use @ in the comment, otherwise I may not receive the notification.